# Add a default class on all text fields in a Yii app

Tags: php, css, yii

I have a bunch of CRUD forms auto generated with Gii, and most them use the CActiveForm widget, but some use CHtml.

I would like to add a default CSS class to all form elements generated with CActiveForm and CHtml. I know that I need to use the widget factory in confing/main.php, but I am struggling to get the right code.

So far I have:

```
    'widgetFactory'=>array(
          'widgets'=>array(
                'CActiveForm'=>array(
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                ),
           ),
    ),
```

**EDIT**: The reason I need this is because I am using twitter bootstrap, and bootstrap makes the fields look really nice by adding form-control class. I don't know how to do this by adding a class to the form. If you have a solution, than I don't need the widget factory.

Comment: It may be easier to simply alter your CSS to select the elements rather than by that particular class, but by the fact that they are form elements within another class, id, or element. If you have a class applied to EVERY form field, you're using CSS "wrong".

Comment: u can do this with jquery... what i know that every gii generated form has a div with classname form ... so you can do it via $('.form').find('input').addClass('form-Control') ...

Comment: hey if you really want to do that you can also play with gii template... and create form with desired class...  its ...  under this path ....   yii\framework\gii\generators\form\templates

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap, and it wants a form-control class on each input. I have not found a solution to make all inputs form-control with adding only a class on the form.

Answer (score 0):

hey you can do that as i said..... under this path change the template ... it will auto generate the form the way you want....   yii\framework\gii\generators\form\templates/ here in form.php you can apply.... if its v1.1.14 then on line number 22

```
 you can chnage line

        <?php echo "<?php echo \$form->textField(\$model,'$attribute'); ?>\n"; ?>

 from this to 
 this line

<?php echo "<?php echo \$form->textField(\$model,'$attribute',array('class'=>'form-control')); ?>\n"; ?>
```

may be your prob solved.... Cheeers....

it will create form from gii with desired class... you can change the template like you want... and mmake it more attractive...

Comment: Not normally a great idea to modify the core files. You can create your own Gii modules with your own templates

Comment: yes ... i was saying that just you have to change the path of the template... there are user interface to change the template... and you can create your own template folder under default (yii\framework\gii\generators\form\templates\default) it is default ... template...   under t5his folder  yii\framework\gii\generators\form\templates\